# Java: JSON with Multicast/Broadcast

Tags: java, json, network-programming

I'm having a play around with JSON in a simple network environment and trying to work out about using unicast/multicast/broadcast with JSON.

I've already got a TCP server running fine accepting JSON objects and parsing them, however if I start with Multicast/Broadcast then I've got to use datagrams and I'm not sure if I"ll be wasting my time with this, or if there is a better approach to the problem.

Any ideas?

PS
I'm using JSON 2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any reasons not to use JSON with multicasting. You have to remember, though, that when using UDP, datagrams can be delivered in different order, or not delivered at all - so you shouldn't split your JSON objects across several datagrams, and not depend on order / delivery in your client apps.